# A delicate elementary inequality

Tags: inequalities

The following "piecewise-quadratic" inequality emerged in a joint work of Rom
Pinchasi and myself. The inequality is surprisingly delicate, and all our
attempts to simplify it made it false. By the end of the day, we were able to
prove the inequality, but the proof is unreasonably sophisticated, totalling
to about 15 pages. We would be happy to have a shorter proof.

The inequality involves the function $G$ of three real variables, defined as
follows: if $(\xi,\eta,\zeta)$ is a non-decreasing rearrangement of
$(x,y,z)$, then we let
  $$ G(x,y,z) := \begin{cases}
                   \xi\eta &\ \text{if}\ \zeta\ge \xi+\eta, \\
                   \xi\eta-\frac14\,(\xi+\eta-\zeta)^2 &\ \text{if}\ \zeta\le \xi+\eta.
                 \end{cases} $$
Thus, for instance, we have $G(9,6,7)=38$, whereas $G(7,14,6)=42$. Now
consider the function $f$ of four variables defined by
$$\begin{align*}
  f(x_0,x_1,y_0,y_1)
    &:= \min \{ 0.15s^2, x_0y_0+x_1y_1 \}  \\
    &\qquad + G(x_0,y_1,1-s) + G(x_1,y_0,1-s)  \\
    &\qquad + 0.25(1-s)^2,
\end{align*}$$
where for brevity I write $s=x_0+x_1+y_0+y_1$, and let
  $$ \Omega := \{ (x_0,x_1,y_0,y_1)\in{\mathbb R}_{\ge 0}^4\colon 1/2 \le s \le 1. \}. $$
All we want to show is that
  $$ \max_\Omega f \le 0.15. $$
(Indeed, the maximum is actually *equal* to $0.15$: say, we have
$f(0.5,0,0.5,0)=0.15$.)

---

At Pat Devlin's suggestion, here is the graph of the maximum as a function of the sum $s=x_0+x_1+y_0+y_1$.

[image: The graph]
<sub>(source: [haifa.ac.il](http://math.haifa.ac.il/~seva/MathOverflow/x0x1y0y1.jpg))</sub>

It looks nice, but does not seem to be a graph of some "simple" function; and so, there is probably no simple analytic expression for $\max f$ over all quadruples $(x_0,x_1,y_0,y_1)$ adding up to $s$.

Comment: Well clearly $G(x,y,z)$ is invariant under permutations of the input, and also $f(x_0, x_1, y_0, y_1) = f(x_1, x_0, y_1, y_0) = f(y_0, y_1, x_0, x_1) = f(y_1, y_0, x_1, x_0)$.  So if it helps, we can assume something like $x_0$ is the minimum of $x_0, x_1, y_0, y_1$.  Where did terms like $0.15 s^2$ or $0.25 (1-s)^2$ come from?  I ask because there may be a stronger (true) inequality that's easier to prove [such as one that replaces $0.25 (1-s)^2$ with something like $(s/4)(1-s)^2$].

Comment: Well, for *any* inequality there is always a stronger inequality (as for any non-negative functions there is a smaller non-negative function); the problem is to find a stronger inequality which **is** easier to prove. In our case, replacing $0.25(1-s)^2$ with $(s/4)(1-s)^2$ actually leads to a *weaker* inequality.

Comment: This is true if one of $x_0, x_1, y_0, y_1$ are equal to $0$, (so WLOG, $x_0 = 0$).  This is because in this case, $f$ simplifies to $min\{0.15 s^2, x_1 y_1\} + 0.25 s^2$.  Then to maximize this, we may assume $y_0 =0$.  Then we can assume $x_1 = y_1 = s/2$.  The resulting function is then maximized exactly at $(0, 0.5, 0, 0.5)$, which yields $0.15$.

Similarly, the claim is also true if $s=1$, then $f$ simplifies to just $min\{0.15, x_0 y_0 + x_1 y_1\} \leq 0.15$.

Comment: And if $s=1/2$, then $f$ simplifies to $\min\{0.15/4, x_0 y_0 + x_1 y_1\}+x_0 y_1-1/4 (x_1 + y_0)^2 + x_1 y_0 -1/4 (x_0 + y_1)^2 + 1/16$ [which no longer contains the function $G$].  This is probably bounded by $0.15$ (but I don't care to check that).  If this in fact the case, then my previous comment would imply that the bound on $f$ need only be checked on the interior of $\Omega$.

Comment: What we really need to know is: what is depicted in your MO icon?

Comment: It could be an elephant sitting on a bench along the water, looking out to sea.

Comment: @Will Jagy: http://www.magicwallpapers.net/host/magicwallpapers.net/upload/wall/res/12/1215-alone-elephant-hd-1280x800-1.jpg

Comment: @Will Jagy: now that your curiosity is satisfied, it is time to satisfy mine...

Comment: Perhaps it would help to think of $s$ as fixed.  Then we are trying to maximize $f$ with the constraint that $s = x_0 + x_1 + y_0 + y_1$.  Then we could think of using the method of Lagrange multipliers.  This reasoning would hopefully reveal that a global maximum of $f$ can only occur at a few special values of $s$ [which can then be checked individually].

Comment: Is it true that the value $0.15$ is achieved also for some $s$ less than one, as the graph shows? Or it is just close to that?

Comment: @Ilya: yes, it is achieved at $s=0.8$; say, $f(0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2)=0.15$. This is an amazingly tight (and tough) inequality... 

Answer (score 7):

The paper where the inequality in question emerged is, finally, written (and
uploaded to the [arXiv](http://arxiv.org/abs/1211.6567), in case anybody is interested). We were
eventually able to simplify the proof and squeeze it down to just about
six pages; indeed, the whole paper is now shorter than our original proof. I
sketch very briefly the new proof below.

We start with the identity
\begin{multline*}
  G((x+y)/2,(x+y)/2,z) = G(x,y,z) \\
     + \frac14(x-y)^2
                - \frac14 \big(\max\{|x-y|-z, 0 \} \big)^2. \tag{1}
\end{multline*}
Once stated, this is easy to verify by a careful case analysis. An immediate
consequence is that $G(x,y,z)$ can only grow if both $x$ and $y$ are replaced
with their average $(x+y)/2$.

As another preparation step, we exploit the internal symmetries of $f$ to
assume, without loss of generality, that
  $$ x_0+x_1 \ge y_0+y_1 \tag{2} $$
and also
  $$ x_0+y_0 \ge x_1+y_1. \tag{3} $$

Our big plan is to investigate how $f$ changes under the balancing operation
which includes replacing $x_0$ and $y_1$ with their average $(x_0+y_1)/2$
and, simultaneously, $x_1$ and $y_0$ with their average $(x_1+y_0)/2$. Using
the identity (1), we could show that either $f$ is non-decreasing under such
balancing, or, under the assumptions (2) and (3), we have
\begin{align*}
  x_0 &\ge y_1+(1-s), \tag{4} \newline
  y_0 &\ge x_1+(1-s), \tag{5}
\end{align*}
and
  $$ 3(x_0+y_0)+(x_1+y_1) \ge 2. \tag{6} $$

The precise meaning of being non-decreasing under balancing is that
  $$ f(x_0,x_1,y_0,y_1) \le f(z_0,z_1,z_1,z_0), $$
where $z_0=(x_0+y_1)/2$ and $z_1=(x_1+y_0)/2$. Consequently, in this case the
problem reduces to maximizing a function of just two variables, which is a
feasible task.

Now, if $f$ is decreasing under balancing, then, in view of (4) and (5) and
by the definition of the function $G$, we have
  $$ G(x_0,y_1,1-s) = y_1(1-s) \ \text{and}\ G(x_1,y_0,1-s)=x_1(1-s). $$
Hence,
\begin{multline*}
  f(x_0,x_1,y_0,y_1) = \min\{0.15s^2,x_0y_0+x_1y_1\} \newline
                                             + (x_1+y_1)(1-s) + 0.25(1-s)^2.
\end{multline*}
The expression in the right-hand side is can only increase if $x_0$ and $y_0$
are both replaced with their average, and, simultaneously, $x_1$ and $y_1$
are replaced with their average. Consequently, we can assume that $x_0=y_0$
and $x_1=y_1$. This, again, reduces the problem to maximizing a function of
two variables, which takes some two more pages to accomplish.